# Reducing number of calls to Database

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am using the following approach to make db calls,

```
 for record in records:
        num = "'"+str(record['Number'])+"'"
        id = "'"+str(record['Id'])+"'"
        query = """select col2_text,col3_text from table where id= {} and num = {} and is_active = 'Y';""".format(id,num)
```

Since it is iteration where total number of DB calls is equal to the number of records. I want to optimize my call and make minimum number of DB calls, ideally in a single call.

Comment: did `records` come out of another query? If so show that too so it can be combined with this one.

Comment: did you try "group by id, num" alongwith your where clause?

Comment: Please provide a short sample of the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the number of DB calls to a single one. You might want to have a look at the [SQL-IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator.

You could do the following:

```
values = ""

for record in records:
    num = "'"+str(record['Number'])+"'"
    id = "'"+str(record['Id'])+"'"
    
    values += "({},{}),".format(num, id)

values = values[:-1]

query = """select col2_text,col3_text from table where (id, num) in ({}) and is_active = 'Y';""".format(values)
```